# How to change ptohoshop actions to relative paths?

Tags: photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

I have several mockups inside a folder with the following structure:

```
mockups
mockups/tshirts
mockups/tshirts/mockup1
mockups/tshirts/mockup1/saved_mockups
mockups/tshirts/mockup2
mockups/pants
mockups/pants/mockup1
mockups/pants/mockup1/saved_mockups
mockups/pants/mockup2
```

Within these folders I have several actions that create different mockups. I would like to share the actions with other people. The problem is that when exporting the actions, the `open`  and `save`  commands are absolute links on my computer.

I would like to know if it is possible to create a script that transforms the commands of the actions in a relative way. To make it easy to perform the actions of another computer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately! Actions paths are absolute and it's one of cons of Actions.

You have 2 solutions I guess. First one would be converting whole Action into `.jsx`, You can easily do this by using one of the [xtools script(ActionToJsx)](http://ps-scripts.sourceforge.net/xtools.html). I personally used this method many times since it seems better than 2nd solution.

Second solution is to split action from `open` and `save` commands. Basically in your case you will make 3 actions by splitting Open and Save commands from action, then you can simply do something like below.

```
app.doAction(action1,set);
//code of opening file; For sure you'll need to define file and folder first
file.open(path)
//now run second split action
app.doAction(action2,set);
//code of saving file;
app.doAction(action3,set);
```

PS. I personally had same situation when I was new to action and I ended up using second solution but later realised that first solution is effective when it comes to controlling.
all you need to do is replace the file locations in script to your desired one. You can find detailed documentation on File and Folder from [this](https://estk.aenhancers.com/3%20-%20File%20System%20Access/file-object.html) site.

Hope it helps you.